# Solution to a second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation $y'' + a/y²$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find a solution to a problem I have in physics, the problem is as following:

$$
ma = u\beta - \frac{GMm}{r²}
$$

Where $u$, $\beta$, $G$, $M$ and $m$ are all constants. I want to find a function of either $a(t)$, $v(t)$ or $r(t)$.

If you rewrite $a$ to $\frac{\partial^2r}{\partial t²}$, divide by $m$ and move $-\frac{GMm}{r²}$ to the left side, you get this equation:

$$
\frac{\partial^2r}{\partial t²} + \frac{GM}{r²} = \frac{u\beta}{m}
$$

which is a second-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation, in the form of:

$$
y'' + \frac{a}{y²} = b
$$

Is there a solution to this differential equation?

Edit: I'm not required understand a method for this [it's probably beyond my level anyway], I just want to know if there exists a general solution and if so; what it is.

Comment: Hint: $$y'(y''+a/y^2-b)=(\tfrac12(y')^2-a/y-by)'$$

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{hint}$

> $y'' = \dfrac{d}{dr}y' = \dfrac{dy}{dr}\dfrac{d}{dy}y' = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dy}y'^2$

thus you equation becomes
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dy}y'^2 =b-\frac{a}{y^2}
$$
setting $\frac{y'^2}{2} = z$ we get
$$
\dfrac{dz}{dy} =b-\frac{a}{y^2}
$$

Comment: Isn't this just another second-degree non-linear ODE? I probably should've clarified that this is way beyond my level as well, I'm just looking for a solution out of curiosity.

Comment: I applaud your desire to go off piste with this topic. As for your question, the original ode is a second order nonlinear ode, however this is an example of reduction of order .. So we go from a nonlinea second order to a first order nonhomogenous ode since we have a function $$z' = f(y)$$ where the prime denotes the derivative of the independent variable.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have the inhomogeneous differential equation of a [radial Kepler orbit](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_trajectory). You can just add the particular solution, which satisfies the RHS, to any solution of the homogeneous differential equation.

This particular solution can be found easily by setting $y''=0$, such that

$$
y_p(t) = \sqrt{\frac ab}.
$$

However the there is no explicit solution to the homogeneous differential equation, only an implicit out for the time as a function of position.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$y'dy'=(b-ay^{-2})dy,$$
$$y'^2=2(by+\frac{a}{y})+C_1,$$
$$\pm\sqrt{\frac{y}{y^2+Cy+\frac{a}{b}}}dy=\sqrt{2b}dt,\,\,\,C=\frac{C_1}{2b},$$

$$\int\pm\sqrt{\frac{y}{y^2+Cy+\frac{a}{b}}}dy=\sqrt{2b}t+D.$$

Integration of LHS can be performed in terms of elliptical functions, but we need to fix the signs of $a$ and $b$, and also give initial conditions $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$ in order to choose the sign of the radical on LHS and calculate $C$ and $D$.

Answer (score 0):

You can write $y''+\frac{a}{y^2}=b$ as $y''+\frac{a}{y^2}-b=0$, and you can multiply by $2y'$, hence $2y'y''+\frac{2ay'}{y^2}-2by'=0$. Notice that $2y'y''=(y'^2)'$ and $\frac{y'}{y^2}=(-\frac{1}{y})'$. Hence $(y'^2-\frac{2a}{y}-2by)'=0$. Thanks to the fundamental theorem of calculus, we have $y'(t)^2-\frac{2a}{y(t)}-2by(t)=y'(0)^2-\frac{2a}{y(0)}-2by(0)$, or simply, let $c=y'(0)^2-\frac{2a}{y(0)}-2by(0)$, so $y'^2=\frac{2a}{y}+2by+c$ or $y'=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2a}{y}+2by+c}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2by^2+cy+2a}{y}}$. So $$\int_{y(0)}^{y(t)}\sqrt\frac{y}{2by^2+cy+a}\,\mathrm{d}y=\pm{t}.$$ The difficult part comes with expressing the integral in terms of some well-known function. This would be much easier if $b=0$, but in the general case, it is more difficult. Anywho, suppose that $$F(s,t,u;x)=\int_0^x\sqrt{\frac{v}{sv^2+tv+u}}\,\mathrm{d}v.$$ Then $$F(2b,c,a;y(t))=F(2b,c,a;y(0))\pm{t}.$$ This is the implicit solution, but there is nothing you can do to go further.